# Initializing state, while testing a component with useState using jest & enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

This question is not for testing state change, but for setting initial value to true. So that menu will be opened and I can test onClick functionally on the opened menu. 
I am using Jest and Enzyme.

**Component:**

```
const CustomHeader = () => {


  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)



  const open = Boolean(anchorEl)

  const handleMenu = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
  }

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null)
  }

  const onProfileClicked = () => {
    dispatch(setProfileShown(true))
    dispatch(setEditMode(false))
    handleClose()
  }

  return (
    <Header position='fixed'>
      <HeaderContent>

        <>
          <ProfileButton
            aria-label='account of current user'
            aria-haspopup='true'
            onClick={handleMenu}
            color='primary'
          >
            <ProfileIcon color='primary' />
            <HeaderTitle variant='subtitle1'>
              &nbsp;{user.firstName}
            </HeaderTitle>
          </ProfileButton>
          <Menu
            id='menu-appbar'
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
          >
            <MenuItem onClick={() => onProfileClicked()}>Profile</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => dispatch(signOut())}>Logout</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </>
      </HeaderContent>
    </Header>
  )
}
```

As you can see, if anchorEl is true Menu will be opened and i can test `onProfileClicked()` is called or not by clicking **Profile** `Menubutton`. My question is, in my test how can I set `anchorEl` to true? As `wrapper.setState()` can only be done for class components and not for functional with hooks.

Answer (score 0):

just trigger appropriate interaction:

```
wrapper.find({ 'aria-label': 'account of current user' }).simulate({ target: document });
```

If you are using `shallow()` you may pass `{target: null}` as well but for `mount()` it depends on `<Menu>` implementation if just a `document` would work or if you need to pass some nested DOM element.

Comment: Thank you @skyboyer for the response. Passing 'document' I get an error saying event[object object] did not find. 
I am doing simulate('click') on the icon button and I see both anchorEl and open has right values. But still, the modal is not shown.

```

it('Verify the setState for setting anchorEl to true is called on profileIcon clicked', () => {
    wrapper
      .find('ForwardRef(IconButton)')
      .at(1)
      .simulate('click')
    expect(mockSetAnchorEl).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true)

console.log(wrapper.debug()) //this console do not prints the modal.

```

Comment: Here is the code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-grass-nsqzo